# Mysql UPDATE table with nearest location

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables :

-cities (id, name, city_latitude, city_longitude, station_id)

-stations (id, name, station_latitude, station_longitude)

I want to UPDATE cities.station_id with the id of the nearest station, within the limit of 30 km

For the moment I can only achieve this :

```
UPDATE cities C, staions S
SET C.station_id = S.id
WHERE (((acos(sin((S.station_latitude*pi()/180)) * sin((city_latitude*pi()/180)) + cos((S.station_latitude *pi()/180)) * cos((city_latitude*pi()/180)) * cos(((S.station_longitude - city_longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) < 30
```

This query update the cities.station_id with random stations.id located  at less than 30km . 
But I really want the nearest, which is not over 30 km
I tried without success "GROUP BY", "LIMIT" or "MIN" but I have syntax errors.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For each city within 30km of a station, are you able to SELECT the nearest station for that city?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this.

`JOIN` on a subselect that orders the `WHERE` as `ASC`, and `LIMIT` 1.

```
UPDATE cities c
JOIN  (
        SELECT  id 
        FROM    station s             
        ORDER BY (((acos(sin((S.station_latitude*pi()/180)) * sin((c.city_latitude*pi()/180)) + cos((S.station_latitude *pi()/180)) * cos((c.city_latitude*pi()/180)) * cos(((S.station_longitude - c.city_longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) ASC        
        LIMIT 1) s
SET c.station_id=s.id
```